# How to get result from database based on the user with laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, backend

I started coding laravel and everything was fine till I wanted to get the result based on the user, how to do it, what do I need to do?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use where clause.

Suppose you wanna fetch all the blogs of a user.

like:

```php
Blog::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

// Auth::user()->id returns the logged in user's id.
```

Or

create a relation in User model

```php
App\Models\User
```

```php
use App\Models\Blog;

 public function blogs()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
 }
```

Then

```php
Auth::user()->blogs;
```

Comment: Thank you so much it was simple but I thought that its harder.